# What is the use of setTokenizer

Tags: android

//What is the use of mact.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
//please see end of code to find this code line

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private AutoCompleteTextView act;
private MultiAutoCompleteTextView mact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    String[] countries=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_of_countries);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);

    act=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    mact=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);

    act.setAdapter(adapter);
    mact.setAdapter(adapter);
    //******************************************************************
    mact.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

****************************Find XML* *********************************

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView 
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
      android:ems="10">
    <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>

    <MultiAutocompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:ems="10" />

     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:text="@string/auto_complete"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
      android:text="@string/multi_auto_complete"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am Getting force close when i run this application


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.autocomplete/com.example.autocomplete.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException:


 Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class MultiAutocompleteTextView

Comment: At where is says add context???

Comment: @Piyush Please find XML file